# how to add the column values or oracle database

Tags: sql, addition

i had 7 tables having similar column names (ex jan1)  with the numerical data values present in it  (ex 1 or 0)   and want to sum up those  and update it in other table having similar  column name (ex  jan1)

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Show some sample data and desired result.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT SUM(size) AS overallSize FROM table WHERE bla = 5;

```
SELECT SUM(SIZE)
FROM Table
WHERE bla = '5'
```